# result from AnonymousThread - how?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe5

I try to make a function:

```
function MyFunction(parameter:string) : string;
begin
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure ()
      var temp : string;
      begin
           temp := paramet;
           //some works on temp variable
           result := temp; <-- error here because it is a procedure
      end).Start;
end;
```

how to make MyFunction return temp variable after the thread end?

Also I tried that way:

```
function MyFunction(parameter:string) : string;
vat temp : string;
begin
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure ()
      begin
           temp := paramet;
            //some works on temp variable
      end).Start;
result := temp;
end;
```

in this way it compiles but returns an empty string. the function returns result and does not wait for end the thread.

Or maybe I'm doing it wrong way because I did not find any example how to do it this way?

Comment: If `MyFunction` needs to wait for a result before exiting then there is no point in using a thread at all.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use TTask.IFuture from the new parallel programming library?
It does exactly what you need, in a very concise and elegant way:

```
FutureObject := TTask.Future<Integer>(function: Integer
     begin
        Sleep(3000);   // to simulate "background processing"
        Result := 16;  // result to be returned as "FutureObject.Value"
     end);

MyValue := FutureObject.Value;  // this waits for the value to be available, if it isn't yet
```

(example taken from this embarcadero wiki page http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_TTask.IFuture_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a result from an anonymous thread. `MyFunction` returns immediately, before the thread is finished.

---

One solution is to use a completion handler that is called after the thread is done doing its job.

```
procedure MyProc(parameter: string; Completion: TProc<string>);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      temp: string;
    begin
      // do something with parameter 
      temp := UpperCase(parameter);
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          Completion(temp);
        end);
    end).Start;
end;
```

And then you call it like:

```
  MyProc('abc',
    procedure(AValue: string)
    begin
      // do whatever you want with AValue
      Label1.Text := AValue;
    end);
```

Comment: First solution return empty string (first return and then run my thread)
Second solution: What unit I have to add to uses? and TTask or ITask type?

Comment: You missed the point of first solution. It is procedure not an function, if you turn it into function it will not work, for the same reason your second example does not work.

Comment: TTask was introduced in XE7. That leaves you with using callback procedure when task is completed.